# Context object not showing the Include method in EntityFrameWorkCore

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using EntityFrameworkCore in my .NetCore application  have used the scafolding command to generate the following classes. Basically I need to write the repository method that would take application code and language code as parameters and return the translation.

Currently I am not able to use the include using my context object

For eg. _context.onSscreenTextTranslation.Include

The include doesn't show up.  Could somebody tell me why it is not showing up and what other way could i do to achieve what I am looking for

Database

```
CREATE TABLE multilingual.OnScreenText
(
    OnScreenTextId int not null PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1),
    OnScreenTextCode varchar(150) Unique(applicationcode,OnScreenTextCode), --(Unique constraint) <- naming convention to guarantee uniqueness <namespace>.<scope>.<textidentifier> e.g. GEH.WIZARD.SCREEN1.DESCRIPTION GEH.WIZARD.SCREEN2.DESCRIPTION
    ApplicationCode varchar(150)
)

Create TABLE multilingual.LanguageCode
(
  LanguageId int not null PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1),
  LanguageCode varchar(6) Unique ,
  LanguageDesc varchar(100) Unique ,
  IsDefault bit DEFAULT 0 ,
  IsDisabled bit DEFAULT 0
)


CREATE TABLE multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation
(
    OnScreenTextTranslationId int not null PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1),
    OnScreenTextId int foreign key references  multilingual.OnScreenText(OnScreenTextId), --<- FK to __OnScreenText__.OnScreenTextId
    LanguageId int foreign key references  multilingual.LanguageCode(LanguageId),
    OnScreenTextValue nvarchar(max) 
)
```

OnScreenText

```
 public partial class OnScreenText
    {
        public OnScreenText()
        {
            OnScreenTextTranslation = new HashSet<OnScreenTextTranslation>();
        }

        public int OnScreenTextId { get; set; }
        public string OnScreenTextCode { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationCode { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OnScreenTextTranslation> OnScreenTextTranslation { get; set; }
    }
```

OnScreenTextTranslation

```
 public partial class OnScreenTextTranslation
    {
        public int OnScreenTextTranslationId { get; set; }
        public int? OnScreenTextId { get; set; }
        public int? LanguageId { get; set; }
        public string OnScreenTextValue { get; set; }

        public virtual LanguageCode Language { get; set; }
        public virtual OnScreenText OnScreenText { get; set; }
    }
```

Context

```
public partial class CoreCommonContext : DbContext
    {
        public CoreCommonContext()
        {
        }

        public CoreCommonContext(DbContextOptions<CoreCommonContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<LanguageCode> LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<OnScreenText> OnScreenText { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<OnScreenTextTranslation> OnScreenTextTranslation { get; set; }

     

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.6-servicing-10079");

            modelBuilder.Entity<LanguageCode>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.LanguageId)
                    .HasName("PK__Language__B93855AB1E5AF3BF");

                entity.ToTable("LanguageCode", "multilingual");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.LanguageCode1)
                    .HasName("UQ__Language__8B8C8A347397D80A")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.LanguageDesc)
                    .HasName("UQ__Language__FBFF6980AA6C7CFA")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.Property(e => e.LanguageCode1)
                    .HasColumnName("LanguageCode")
                    .HasMaxLength(6)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.LanguageDesc)
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<OnScreenText>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("OnScreenText", "multilingual");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.ApplicationCode, e.OnScreenTextCode })
                    .HasName("UQ__OnScreen__137EDFB02693385E")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.Property(e => e.ApplicationCode)
                    .HasMaxLength(150)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.OnScreenTextCode)
                    .HasMaxLength(150)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<OnScreenTextTranslation>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("OnScreenTextTranslation", "multilingual");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Language)
                    .WithMany(p => p.OnScreenTextTranslation)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.LanguageId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__OnScreenT__Langu__4CC05EF3");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.OnScreenText)
                    .WithMany(p => p.OnScreenTextTranslation)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.OnScreenTextId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__OnScreenT__OnScr__4BCC3ABA");
            });
        }
    }
```

Repository method

```
public class CoreCommonQuery
    {
        private readonly CoreCommonContext _context;

        public CoreCommonQuery(CoreCommonContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public dynamic GetApplicationTranslations(string applicationCode, string languageCode)
        {
            var result = _context.OnScreenTextTranslation
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`?

Comment: Yes I am using entityframeworkcore

Comment: Is that statement in your CoreCommonQuery class file? I believe that needs to be there or the Include() method will not show. I believe I've seen where it doesn't even recommend it, or it at least requires you to add the package to that specific Project. If you have your Solution split into multiple Projects, that might be why it is not there. Try adding `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` at the top of CoreCommonQuery.